# Get users information in Woocommerce email template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I am trying to send customized email notifications to my customers and I need to get the customer information like First name, E-Mail address, Last name … etc.

Where can I get customer information for email templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly on all related email Woocommerce templates, you can use the `WC_Order` Object `$order` variable. So from this `WC_Order` Object you can use the following:

Then you can get all details using available [`WC_Order` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) this way:

```
$first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name(); // First name
$Last_name  = $order->get_billing_last_name(); // Last name
$email      = $order->get_billing_email(); // Email address
```

> For other user needed details see: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Thank you for your help!